# Codeigniter : what if I want both URL with index.php and without index.php work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, uploadify

I want both `index.php` included, and `index.php` excluded from my URIs to work smoothly on my site. I need it because of uploadify not working, and it is giving me a HTTP error.

It works if I have changed this

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

to this

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

, but then whole system is not working properly.

Comment: Just make sure to go through the tutorial to get the site working without `index.php`.

Then, even if you use index.php, it will work.

[Here's one method of using .htaccess to remove index.php](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have referred that link many times and get resolved the issue with that. but the problem is, if I am accessing the site with index.php contained URL then all the assets path will have index.php with it. and which I do not want there. like, `index.php/assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your assets, first, on `config.php` set the `$config['base_url']` to your website URL.

Then, when linking to assets on which you do NOT want index.php, just use the function `base_url`

```
<?php echo base_url("assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf"); ?>
// Generates http://URL/assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link in the comment from Indranil above to remove index.php from your URIs by modifying your `.htaccess` file.

Here is the address again for reference:

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
```

Keep in mind too that this can vary from host to host in the way that it needs to be formatted, so follow up on that with your hosting service. Most usually have guides that show you how to configure this properly.

I'd also like to know how you're using your links, but I'll go ahead and explain what I think may be happening to you. If you're doing any kind of link/anchor or `redirect()` using the URL Helper in CodeIgniter, then make sure you're using the right function to execute those actions. Here's what I mean:

The `site_url()` function/method will always include index.php in your URIs. Here's an example using the site name `http://example.com` as your website's domain.

`<?php echo site_url('home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/index.php/home`

While `base_url()` function/method will always exclude index.php unless you include it. Here's an example using the site name `http://example.com` as your website's domain.

`<?php echo base_url('home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/home`

and

`<?php echo base_url('index.php/home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/index.php/home`

Keep in mind that using these functions/methods are only effective AFTER you have properly modified your `.htaccess` file.

Here is the link that shows you a more in-depth difference between the `site_url()` and `base_url()` functions.

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html
```

I hope this helps!